# Testing to see if port is in use before initializing bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot and have a bean that initializes an `EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer`. I have a property file in which a user supplies a port and ip address to bind to (thus the need for an `EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer` because the port is not the default that Spring boot uses). How can I test to see if the address and port combination is already in use prior to initializing this bean? I am not able to create a `ServerSocket` inside of this bean. I wish to have a graceful way of catching this exception and logging it. In the case that the port/ip combination is in use, Spring will shutdown with a stacktrace.

```
    @Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer embeddedServletContainerCustomizer() throws UnknownHostException {
    EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer embeddedServletContainerCustomizer = null;

    embeddedServletContainerCustomizer = new EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {
        @Override
        public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
            container.setPort(port);
            container.setAddress(inetAddress);
        }
    };

    return embeddedServletContainerCustomizer;
}
```

Comment: Why would you need a configuration for that? You can just configure `server.port` or add a `server.port=${your.property:8080}` which will then replace `server.port` with your value or `8080` when not set). So you don't need your customizer. Also instead of detecting the port I suggest to write a `FailureAnalyzer` for this case (and I believe there already is one for this case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Spring SocketUtils](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/SocketUtils.html)
For example

```
SocketUtils.findAvailableTcpPort(startRange, endRange);
```

Comment: SocketUtils is just creating a ServerSocket to see if it works: 
 https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/bc14c5ba83e1f211628456bbccce7b2531aac58c/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/util/SocketUtils.java.  Whatever's limiting OP from creating ServerSockets may also restrict this solution

Comment: I think limitation (most probably security) is to create socket connection, but not to listen to socket connection.